# Can't make CSS overrides on Wordpress Child theme. Used one-click-child theme and a bootstrap theme

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, parent-child

I've created child themes before using the same method, but for some reason with Bootstrap3 themes (I've tried multiple) I can't override the CSS. I'm currently using this  [Flatty theme](http://wordpress.org/themes/flatty).

I'm thinking maybe the trouble comes from the fact that there is a style.css in the parent but the styles I'm attempting to change are in a css folder in a file called main.css. I've tried duplicating this folder and file as well, but no luck. I've also tried just putting the classes I want to change in my child style.css.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you made any changes in the Customizer?

Comment: No, I haven't touched much of anything yet because the main things I need to tackle first are in the stylesheet.

Comment: http://tech-papers.org/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme/

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS file needs to load *after* Bootstrap's CSS file. That way, your styles with the same name as Bootstrap's styles will take precedence.

Comment: Thanks henry, could you elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: In the <head> section of your theme's header.php you should have a link to Bootstrap's css file and a link to your own style.css. Make sure the link to your style.css comes *after* the link to Bootstrap's css file. Then, you'd simply add your own styles to style.css which will override Bootstrap's styles.